# VLAN Inheritance?

Tags: networking, vlan

Imagine the following scenario:

```
    Primary Switch
          |
    (VLAN 3 Port)
          |
   Unmanaged Switch
  (Dedicated to IPMI
      Interfaces)
          |
         / \
        /   \
Server 1    Server 2
 (IPMI)      (iDRAC)
```

Would the clients on the unmanaged switch automatically become part of VLAN 3 when trying to communicate the the rest of the network?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Assuming that the unmanaged switch is just a dumb L2 device, it will be on the same L2 domain as everything else on VLAN 3.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as you aren't tagging traffic through that port, it is just a dumb L2 switch.